# Minimize the Refrigerator distance from the back wall

Tags: vent, refrigerator

I would like to minimize (as much as possible) the distance of the refrigerator from the back wall. I already scrubbed as much plaster as possible from the back wall (behind the plaster is a concrete pillar and I don't want to dig in to that) and would like to push the refrigerator so it is touching the wall. I'm willing to build a ventilation system to take the hot air out but not sure if this is a good idea or will work.

What should be the nominal temperature at the back of a refrigerator? Is adding a vent a good idea? Any alternative solutions? Refrigerator is RF60J9000 and the recommended space in the back is 2" (50mm)

Comment: I am having trouble identifying the fridge.  Is that a Samsung model intended for the Italian market, like [this](http://www.trovaprezzi.it/prezzo_frigoriferi-congelatori_samsung_rf_60j9000.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, that's the one

Comment: @Gilad Did you move forward with this? I have a similar situation.